# How to escape $ in java?

Tags: java, regex, special-characters

I am trying below code but getting error

```
String x = "aaa XXX bbb";
    String replace = "XXX";
    String y = "xy$z";
    String z=y.replaceAll("$", "\\$");
    x = x.replaceFirst(replace, z);
    System.out.println(x);
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceFirst(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.replaceFirst(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

I want result as

```
aaa xy$z bbb
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead, which doesn't use regular expressions, since you don't need them at all:

```
String x = "aaa XXX bbb";
String replace = "XXX";
String y = "xy$z";
x = x.replace(replace, y);
System.out.println(x);
```

This will print `aaa xy$z bbb`, as expected.

Answer (score 3):

If the replacement string includes a dollar sign or a backslash character, you should use

```
Matcher.quoteReplacement()
```

So change

```
String z=y.replaceAll("$", "\\$");`
```

to

```
String z = Matcher.quoteReplacement(y);
```

Comment: doing `String z=y.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\$");` - still won't compile

Comment: Now it will print `aaa xy\$z bbb` when you really want `aaa xy$z bbb`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that after the line:

```
String z=y.replaceAll("$", "\\$");
```

The value of `z` is: `xy$z$`
what you really want to do is:

```
String x = "aaa XXX bbb";
String replace = "XXX";
String y = "xy\\$z";            
x = x.replaceFirst(replace, y);
System.out.println(x);
```

which will output:

```
aaa xy$z bbb
```